# Why does a blank .tex file not compile?

Tags: pdftex, compiling

When I compile with `pdflatex.exe` or `latex.exe`  the empty document below, I get no errors, no warnings, and no pages of output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Why is nothing produced? Is there no such thing as an empty `.pdf` or `.dvi` file?

(I'm just curious; I don't need an empty file.)

Comment: Because there are no paragraphs to output.  If you want a blank pdf, write `\null` or `\leavevmode` after `\begin{document}`.  Both commands start a paragraph, then TeX has something to output (even it visually empty)

Comment: There was a question somewhere about the difference of a blank LaTeX and a blank Plain TeX document, but I can't find it now.  I think the answers there are what you're looking for

Comment: Interesting. Feels a bit like set theory, where the empty set `{}` is different than the set containing just the empty set, `{{}}`. TeX doesn't want to output an empty document, but it will output a document that contains only an empty paragraph.

Comment: Kind of, yes.  When you write `\null`, you tell TeX to add an empty box to a (future) paragraph.  Then, TeX builds that paragraph using that one (empty, but it doesn't care about that now) box.  Then, when building the page it sees that paragraph.  So it's more like `{{{}}}` :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Only a single `\null` does not start a paragraph, nor will this empty box be added to a future paragraph. This `\null` is added while TeX is still in vertical mode, no? Thus, `\leavevmode` starts a paragraph, but `\null` adds an empty line (while still in vertical mode).

Comment: @RuixiZhang Ah, yes, indeed.  It slipped my mind that an `\hbox` in vmode is just added.  My previous comment should've started with "When you write `\leavevmode\null`..."

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik no, your previous comment should have started with "When you write `\leavevmode`..." as that already does add an empty box in horizontal mode which will start a paragraph. `\leavevmode\null` would be `{{{}{}}}` in our set theory language.

Comment: @Skillmon Bah, yes.  That proves I'm not in the set of people that are good at sets :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik actually I think I might be wrong. Since `\unhbox\voidb@x` will not really put an empty box there, but the contents of an empty box... So both `\leavevmode` and `\leavevmode\null` might lead to the same result (have no TeX installation at hand to look at the trace).